# ggmap and scale_colour_brewer

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot a frequency over a map obtained with `ggmap` in R. The idea is that I would have a plot of the frequency on each coordinates set. The frequency ("freq") would be mapped to six and a color scale. The data looks like this:

```
         V7       V6 freq
1   42.1752 -71.2893    1
2   42.1754 -71.2893    1
3   42.1755 -71.2901    2
4   42.1755 -71.2893    1
5   42.1756 -71.2910    1
6   42.1756 -71.2907    1
7   42.1756 -71.2906    1
8   42.1756 -71.2905    1
9   42.1756 -71.2901    1
10  42.1756 -71.2899    2
11  42.1756 -71.2897    2
12  42.1756 -71.2894    2
13  42.1757 -71.2915    1
14  42.1757 -71.2910    1
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
ggmap(newmap2) + 
geom_point(aes(x = coordfreq$V7, y = coordfreq$V6), 
           data = coordfreq, alpha = 1/sqrt(coordfreq$freq),
           colour = coordfreq$freq, size = sqrt(coordfreq$freq)) +
scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

I only get the color mapped to "freq", but I cannot get the `scale_colour_brewer` to work. I have tried several arguments to `scale_color_brewer` to no available.

Comment: A map obtained with any of the ggmap methods

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: newmap2<-get_openstreetmap(bbox = c(left = -71.546023, bottom = 42.345925, right = -71.020990, top = 42.536672),scale=80000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code created a map without data points. Here is possibly what you are after. A few things. One is that you do not have to type `x = coordfreq$V7`. You can just type `x = V7`. The same applies to other similar cases in your code. Another is that `colour` should be in `aes()` in your case. Another thing is that `freq` is numeric. You need it as either factor or character when you assign colours to your graphic. The other is that `freq` is a function. You want to void such a name. Hope this will help you.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

# This get_map code was suggested by an SO user. Sadly, the edit was rejected.
# Credit to him/her (MichaelVE).

newmap2 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -71.2893, lat = 42.1752), 
                   zoom = 17, maptype = 'terrain')

ggmap(newmap2) +
geom_point(data = mydf2, aes(x = V6, y = V7, colour = factor(frequency), size = sqrt(frequency))) +
scale_colour_brewer(palette ="Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelVE Pleasure, mate. :)

Comment: This works fine, thank you! However I omitted (my bad) to mention that frequency ranges 1-900, so scale_colour_brewer does not work. I will work on other methods and come back with more questions.